# Save vector to jpeg with white space

Tags: vector, export, jpg

I have created some vector graphics and tried to convert them to jpeg to put in my portfolio on web. A few got converted but left no margins around, which does not look professional. Another few got converted but I cant see any thing in the display window.

Are there any standards or specifications to avoid these problems?

Comment: Why not use the SVGs directly? The only reason I can think of is if the file sizes are too large

Answer (score 1):

To add white space around your graphics, make sure the artboard is sized how you want, and then check the "Use Artboards" option when you export. It will crop to the artboard size exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, make sure your artboard has the right size before exporting your vector to jpeg. You can also adjust the size of images on web. But in my opinion i would leave it as png for web.

If you have trouble seeing your image on your display you may have used the wrong location to display your image.

Comment: Welcome to GD, Yoshi, and thanks for the contribution!